# How to get a physical vaccine certificate in Germany for international travel?

Tags: air-travel, germany, europe, covid-19, vaccinations

I need to travel from Germany to a country outside of the EU, where the CovPass code is not accepted. Additionally, when I export my vaccination certificate from the app into a PDF, it is mostly in Germany (except for a few tidbits in English).

Therefore, I am curious as to how I can get a physical vaccine certificate that is accepted for international travel.

Comment: How did you get the certificates loaded into the App?  I first received a print-out from my local pharmacy and then loaded that into the app.  I then kept the print-outs just for such a case.  If you no longer have them, then the pharmacy should be able to issue them again if you go with your "Impfpass".   BTW:  The government do suggest keeping the print-outs in case they need to be scanned again, e.g. in case of changing your phone.

Comment: BTW:  It would be helpful if you stated your destination country.  It helps people give correct advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CovPass I am using creates a PDF where all the relevant information is in German and English.

The only portions not in English are the instructions on

- how to scan in the QR-Code
- where to go to find information for other EU countries conditions

none of which is required to varify your vaccination status.

Comment: Is the PDF then valid for international travel or only for travel within the EU?

Comment: @SkiMask 33 other countries use the same system: [Mutual recognition of COVID certificates by the EU and third (non-EU) countries](https://ec.europa.eu/info/live-work-travel-eu/coronavirus-response/safe-covid-19-vaccines-europeans/eu-digital-covid-certificate_en#mutual-recognition-of-covid-certificates-by-the-eu-and-third-non-eu-countries). Otherwise you must check the countries not listed in the link. Reports on this site state that Canada does accept it. An extra print out, as an extra precaution, would be a good idea.